# submitting a job array script on SGE

Tags: shell-script, files, gridengine

I am trying to make a job array script to do a particular task for several files. Let's assume as a start for only 2 fastq files. Name : abc.fastq , def.fastq

```
#!/bin/bash

    file=$(ls -1 *.fastq | tail -n +${SGE_TASK_ID}| head -1)
    filename=${file%.fastq}
    awk 'NR % 2 == 0{print substr($1,7,100)};NR % 2 ==1' $file > ${filename}_BR.fastq
```

I submitted the script as:

```
qsub -t 1-2:1 -cwd -j y -N array_job ./jobarray.sh
```

But only 1 file is processed which is abc.fastq. What happened to the def.fastq file?. I provided the -t parameter with 2 jobs and SGE_TASK_ID is declared in my script.

Hope to hear from you guys soon.

Comment: I just ran across this old question; I'm not familiar with SGE/gridengine -- does SGE_TASK_ID get set to 1 and then 2 in separate instances of calling jobarray.sh?

Comment: Yes it does. It get's that information from -t parameter on qsub line